# Connecting SAMBA Printer

Tags: networking, windows, printing, samba, windows-10

I have a mostly Windows network. One of the PCs has a shared printer. When trying to print from Ubuntu, the print queue shows in the status column "Held for authentication".
Any ideas about what this means? How can I print over the network?

Answer (score 0):

This could be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1853743. In fact, they look like duplicates of each other at the moment.